# NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, nhibernate-mapping

I'm newbie in NHibernate. I'm trying using this ORM with SQLite.
I have the following:
[image: project]

**Product.cs**

```
namespace Stock.Models.Classes
{
    class Product
    {
        public virtual string Name {get; set;}
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Product.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                  assembly="Stock.Models"
                  namespace="Stock.Models.Classes">
  <class name="Product" table="products">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="int" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="Price" />
    <property name="Quantity" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=nhibernate.db;Version=3</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I'm trying to test in Program.cs.
**Program.cs**

```
namespace Stock
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //Application.Run(new Form1());
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.Configure();
                cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Product).Assembly);
        }
    }
}
```

In run time the app breaks in the line `cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Product).Assembly);` with the message in the popup: `Could not compile the mapping document: Stock.Models.Mappings.Product.hbm.xml` and in console:

```
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x10a8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Stock.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\...\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\Stock.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Stock.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\...\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\NHibernate.dll'
'Stock.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Stock.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'jsw3tdap'
'Stock.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\...\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\Iesi.Collections.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.MappingException' occurred in NHibernate.dll
```

If I add a try/catch in **Program.cs** :

```
 try
    {
        cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Product).Assembly);
    }
 catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }
```

I get (console):

```
A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.MappingException' occurred in NHibernate.dll
NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: Stock.Models.Mappings.Product.hbm.xml ---> NHibernate.MappingException: persistent class Stock.Models.Classes.Product, Stock.Models not found ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Stock.Models' or one of its dependencies. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at NHibernate.Util.ReflectHelper.TypeFromAssembly(AssemblyQualifiedTypeName name, Boolean throwOnError)
   at NHibernate.Util.ReflectHelper.ClassForName(String name)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder.ClassForFullNameChecked(String fullName, String errorMessage)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder.ClassForFullNameChecked(String fullName, String errorMessage)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder.ClassForNameChecked(String name, Mappings mappings, String errorMessage)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.ClassBinder.BindClass(IEntityMapping classMapping, PersistentClass model, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.RootClassBinder.Bind(HbmClass classSchema, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.AddRootClasses(HbmClass rootClass, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.AddEntitiesMappings(HbmMapping mappingSchema, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.Bind(HbmMapping mappingSchema)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMapping mappingDocument, String documentFileName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMapping mappingDocument, String documentFileName)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument(NamedXmlDocument doc)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ProcessMappingsQueue()
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDocumentThroughQueue(NamedXmlDocument document)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddXmlReader(XmlReaThe thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0x1700) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x5d4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[4428] Stock.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[4428] Stock.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
der hbmReader, String name)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream, String name)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddResource(String path, Assembly assembly)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly assembly)
   at Stock.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Cristhian\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 25
```

XML files are seted as `Embedded Resource` and `Copy Always`. Why does not compile the mapping document Stock.Models.Mappings.Product.hbm.xml? Is it a problem of file format or a library dll problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, the `Stock.Models` assembly doesn't exist. The only assembly that exists is `Stock`, so you need to change your mapping file accordingly:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                  assembly="Stock"
                  namespace="Stock.Models.Classes">
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error despite my mapping files being correct.

Turns out the updated assemblies were not present in the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\<port>\bin` folder. When I copied them across by hand it worked.

I don't have an explanation as to why they aren't getting copied across yet or even if they should be, I'm only posting this as an answer as it fixed my issue and I haven't seen it documented anywhere else online.

Answer (score 1):

you should add assembly and namespace in hbm.xml file.for to find what assemply name use of typeof(yourModel).Assembly and check fullName.
name of Assembly and class not same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's in the "assembly" and "namespace". What I did to resolve it, was to name both, in your example, "Stock".

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                  assembly="Stock"
                  namespace="Stock">
```

Comment: I deleted the hbm.xml file and still get the same error.